# When "much" is used as an adverb, can it be used to modify a verb?

Tags: verbs, adverbs

When "much" is used as an **adverb**, can it be used to modify a **verb**? Does "We all **love** him **much**" make sense to you, native speakers?

Comment: "We all love him very much" makes sense." Without the very, it's awkward.

Comment: Did it hurt much?

Comment: strangely, putting 'so' before much makes it perfectly acceptable! Natives? this is a good question +1

Comment: An adverb can modify a verb. You are right on that. Though an adverb can't modify only a verb, it can others also. Different adverbs work differently. Yes, **much** modify a verb - *"You haven't changed much since I last saw you."*.

Comment: @MaulikV "So" works just as well here you're right. Although it would be correct to say "We gave him much love", you're almost always going to encounter something to augment like "so", "very", "so very" before the use of much.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire The ***much*** in *"We gave him much love."* is not an adverb. It's a determiner. Just an aside :-)

Comment: @Man_From_India yeah I was just referring to what is common and thus "more natural" in speech you'd encounter in the wild. :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire true :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the word much can be used as an adverb.

As per Technic Empire's comments, you should say "We all love him very much". You  use very with much in positive sentences. However, you can use much without very in negative sentences. Please look at the following examples of the use of much as an adverb modifying verbs.

He didn't help much.

Thank you very much for the help.

I would very much like to go with you.

I didn't enjoy it much.

I enjoyed it very much.